# How to set image position in Unity?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, user-interface

How to set the y-coordinate of the image to the x-coordinate of the world space transform in unity c# script?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GuageFollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(player.transform.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you want to get the x position and what do you want to set the y position of?

Comment: This questions need more and better context XD